# why my if condition for checking interger is not working?

Tags: php

```
             if($row['rank_code'] == 13 or 14)
              {
                //admin panel
                header("location:home_1");
                $_SESSION["hname"] = "$hname";
                exit();
              }
              elseif($row['rank_code'] == 7 or 8 or 9 or 10 or 11 or 12)
              {
                //senior panel
                header("location:home_2");
                $_SESSION["hname"] = "$hname";
                exit();
              }
              elseif($row['rank_code'] == 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6)
              {
                //junior panel
                header("location:home_3");
                $_SESSION["hname"] = "$hname";
                exit();
             }
```

As I want to redirect my header to home_3 but it always redirecting it to home_1.. 
as the value of $row['rank_code'] is coming from mysql database which is 0..

Comment: Hint: if($row['rank_code'] == 13 or 14) is incorrect.

Comment: oh i don't have any idea.. actually i am so confused right now so its hard to get it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  could compare the rank_code value to arrays with each dest values:

```
$sendAdminPanel = array(13,14);
$sendSeniorPanel = array(7,8,9,10,11);
$sendJuniorPanel = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6);

if (in_array($row['rank_code'],  $sendAdminPanel))
  {
  // go to admin panel
  }
elseif(..)
  {
 // go to senior panel
  }
...
```

Or just checking if the rank_code is between each max and min values. This option renders faster than the previous one:

```
if($val >= 13 && $val <= 14){
  //admin panel
  header("location:home_1");
  $_SESSION["hname"] = "$hname";
  exit();
}elseif($val >= 7 && $val <= 12){
  //senior panel
  header("location:home_2");
  $_SESSION["hname"] = "$hname";
  exit();
}elseif($val >= 0 && $val <= 6){
  //junior panel
  header("location:home_3");
  $_SESSION["hname"] = "$hname";
  exit();
}else{
  echo "rank_code is not valid";
}
```

You can check at php comparison hints here at the docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php
When comparing to many values, try using arrays or some other solution adapted to the kind of compared values.

Comment: Woman! :-P Most welcome :-)
If my answer was useful please do mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement is incorrect
`if($row['rank_code'] == 13 or 14)`

Use
`if($row['rank_code'] == 13 or $row['rank_code'] == 14)`

Using `14` alone returns `true`. Your code works like this
`if( false or true)` which returns true